# How to build a special polygon (a kite shape) with HTML & CSS only?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I'm working on my new project and in this I need some irregular structures. 
One of them is:
[image: Kite shape]

What I achieved is:

```css
.mainkite {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f00;
  transform: skew(180deg, 180deg) rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.midLine {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  transform: skew(180deg, 180deg) rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 99px;
  width: 140%;
  left: -41px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainkite">
  <div class="midLine"></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80qs2a4y/)

How can I get the rest of the shape I desire?

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't use the StackSnippet to provide a live demo inside the question itself? It's just a matter of adding two comments to your question.

Comment: What is StackSnippet ?

Comment: @SunilGehlot StackSnippet is an integrated HTML-JS-CSS demo on SO, as shown by the edit by web-tiki.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

### With CSS :

Using:

- only HTML and CSS
- 2 elements and 2 pseudo elements
- border-radius and transforms for the inner lines
- the [border technique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7073484/1811992) for the bottom triangle

```css
.kite {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  background: #f00;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.kite:before, .kite:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}
.kite:before {
  top: 50%; left: -20.5%;
  width: 141%;
  margin-top:-1px;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.kite:after {
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 198px; height: 198px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
}
.tail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 199px; left: 199px;
  width:60px; height:60px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.tail:before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width:141%; height:100%;
  background:#000;
  transform-origin:0 100%;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="kite"><span class="tail"></span>
</div>
```

### With SVG

Another approach you should consider is using an [inline SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction). As you seem to be making a graphical element, SVG migh be more appropriate semanticaly and :

- be easily scalable
- shorter code
- better control over the shapes and curves

In the following example I use [polyline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polyline) to make the red square,  the bottom black triangle and the vertical line. For the circular line, I use a path element with a [quadratic bezier curve command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves) :

```css
svg{display:block;width:400px;margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 10">
  <polyline fill="red" points="5 0 9 4 5 8 1 4" />
  <polyline points="5 0 5.05 0.05 5.05 7.95 5 8 4.95 7.95 4.95 0.05" />
  <path d="M1.05 4.05 Q5 1 8.95 4.05" fill="none" stroke-width="0.1" stroke="#000" />
  <polyline points="5 8 6 9 4 9 " />
</svg>
```

### Bonus

Thx to [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry) for making me think this out some more and make me find another *CSS* only approach with one div :

```css
.kite {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  background: #f00;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.kite:before, .kite:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}
.kite:before {
  top: 50px; left: -41px;
  width: 282px; height: 2px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background: #000;
  transform-origin: 141px 52px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background-clip: content-box;
  border-right: 50px solid #000;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
.kite:after {
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 198px; height: 198px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="kite"></div>
```

Comment: Those values (142%, -21%)... However, it works! nice :)

Comment: @Vucko I tweaked it a bit to 141% as `141 ~=  √2 * 100 = the diagonal of the square`.

Comment: Awesome... well i have one question though..how to give answer of question related to css/html before web-tiki and harry :p

Comment: I don't know why, but I'm getting a strange drawing error on the tail in the latest Firefox with the CSS version. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ggSC3.png

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I changed the snippet to make the tail and used the [rotation approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24808936/1811992) for the tail. It works for me now in FF

Comment: Hello, There's also gradient, radius and pseudo that can be used from a single element :) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZpGWPd

Comment: nice one @GCyrillus

Answer (score 13):

The answer given by [web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki) is wonderful and I'd recommend using SVG for complex shapes for the same reasons indicated in his answer. This shape however is reasonably simple to create with CSS and below is another variant for creating this with only one element.

The black tail part is a pseudo-element whereas the red kite is its `box-shadow`. The line in the middle is created using a `linear-gradient` on the parent and the curved string is the second pseudo.

I have used viewport units for all the parts to make the output be responsive. This is because the box shadows can't take percentage values and cannot be responsive unless viewport units are used.

```css
.kite {
  position: relative;
  height: 25vw;
  width: 25vw;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent calc(50% - 1px), black calc(50% - 1px), black calc(50% + 1px), transparent calc(50% + 1px));
  overflow: hidden;
}
.kite:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: calc(84.5% + 1px);  /* (15/25 * 1.414 is approximately 84.5% + 1px for correction */
  left: 50%;
  height: 15vw;
  width: 15vw;
  background: black;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  box-shadow: -15vw -15vw 0px red; /* the x and y are same as height and width */
  z-index: -1;
}
.kite:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: calc(0% - 2px);
  left: calc(50% + 1px);
  width: calc(15vw - 2px);
  height: calc(15vw - 1px);
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="kite"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I created two divs for Arc and Tail respectively. I wrapped `mainkite` and `tale` in one div to position tail properly as `mainkite` overflow has been set as `hidden`.

You can see my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/80qs2a4y/7/

**Arc** is created by simply adding `border-radius: 50%;` and increasing width and height to `200%`.

*Ref: Create triangle using CSS ONLY : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/*